# Get file-name in sub-folders along with its information in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have a 'images' folder and inside it are subfolders which have images. What I want is the name all the images along with their path in an array.

I have written this in my controller:

```
$data['images_names'] = directory_map('../project/images/');
```

this is giving be image name, but not path. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this ??

```
$files = dir_scan('/var/www/www/chat/*');
print_r($files);

function dir_scan($folder) {
  $files = glob($folder);
  foreach ($files as $f) {
    if (is_dir($f)) {
      $files = array_merge($files, dir_scan($f . '/*')); // scan subfolder
    }
  }
  return $files;
}
```

from

[PHP get path to every file in folder/subfolder into array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233859/php-get-path-to-every-file-in-folder-subfolder-into-array)